# Write to eip register inside an interrup. Intel IA32 PC Architecture

Tags: assembly, x86, return, intel, i386

Inside the interrupt I want to somehow write the address of a function and go to this address after the interrupt ends into the `EIP` register. But it seems my program goes to this address straight away after settng `EIP` register.
I use

```
jmp eax
```

to move the value of `eax` into `EIP`.

Could you advice me how to do what I want? There should be a way because context switching has to work somehow.

My target CPU is the Intel 80386 (i386) (Intel IA32 PC Architecture).

Comment: What's the exact procedure that you use for handling the interrupts? You should use `iret` to return from an interrupt handling procedure. Without more context, this question is not answerable.

Comment: You should just update the EIP on the stack, of course. That will be popped by the `IRET`.

Comment: "Context switching" will likely have a separate stack for each context. And saved register values. If your interrupt is a timer tick, you will probably want to resume the interrupted code later. Not just jump somewhere else and forget where you came from.

Comment: I wanted to do the context switching inside my interrupt. Inside the interrupt I push the context of my process into its stack and then I pop the context of another process from it's stack. The problem is when I try to write address into EIP by pop eax and then jmp eax I really jump to this adress from the interrupt. But I do not want it happens I want to continue my interrupt and go to this address when I finish my interrupt. I wanted somebody to advice me how to do it...

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are in Protected Mode.

Every interrupt stores a return address on the stack, which it jumps to when the `iret` instruction is encountered.

If an interrupt is fired, the CPU pushes the return address (segment selector + offset) and, after that, the contents of the `eflags` register on the stack.
So, in order to replace the return address's **offset** by some other value, you need to move the return address to `esp + sizeof(eflags) = esp + 04h`.

Expressed in Assembly, Intel syntax<sup>1</sup>:

```
mov [esp + 04h], ret_addr
```

Now, when the `iret` instruction is executed, the ISR will jump to the code `ret_addr` is pointing to.

Note, however, that, if the target code is terminated by `ret` (i.e., a function), you additionally need to push the return address on the stack. This is accomplished by

- `push`ing the offset only onto the stack

or, before, that

- `push`ing the segment selector onto the stack

right where indicated in the code above.

---

Comment: I believe that it looks logical, I will try, thank you

Comment: If it pushes and pops these registers automatically I would rather not touch these registers then. I just switch the pointer to a stack and it pops new data by itself.

Comment: @KosTTT I edited how to replace the return addresses. Hope that's better.